# Use custom HRTF with Google Resonance

Tags: resonance-audio

I'm currently looking into use a particular HRTF database in Unity using Google Resonance. However, I can't find documentation regarding this possibility. Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The Resonance Audio SDKs use a custom HRTF database under the hood, it's not possible to replace it via an external set.

That said, you can refer to [the corresponding spatial-audio section](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatial-audio) in [the public spatial-media repo on GitHub](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) for further information and resources regarding the HRIRs that are used.

Comment: Dear Anokta,

Thanks for your previous answer. Since it's now open source, I do have access to the Sadie dataset and how it's encoded. I do have one question regarding the symmetric_lebedev26 which is the one I'm interested in using for the 3rd order HOA: the angles defined in this .mat file, where do they come from? Are they related to the Sadie dataset?

Thanks for any help